# loading vrml file into three.js java script program

Tags: three.js, vrml

I am not able to load my company vrml(.wrl) model in the three.js java script  program , my .wrl model is 13MB in memory. I would like to know the reason for that and  how can i load that into three.js program?

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: I load the file path in the java script program, keeping the file path in wamp server. But the browser will not display the model. As such it doesn't throw any error messages. Please help.